# Delete vertical and horizontal lines in both axis (tikzpicture)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I have the following figure:

[image]

And I would like to be able to remove all the stripes or lines on the axes, which I enclose in black. This is my code, I would appreciate your help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\usepackage[margin = 0.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            height=5.5cm, width=0.8*\textwidth,
            axis lines=middle,
            %grid, grid style = {dashed},
            xlabel=$s$, xlabel style={anchor=west},
            ylabel style={anchor=south},
            xmin=-4, xmax=4,
            ymin=-3,  ymax=3,
            xticklabels=none, yticklabels=none,
            ]
            \addplot [
            domain=-3.8:3.8, 
            samples=100, 
            thick, smooth,
            ] {sin(deg(3*x))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

Instead of `xticklabels=none, yticklabels=none,` you should write `xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty`. So the complete MWE should be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\usepackage[margin = 0.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            height=5.5cm, width=0.8*\textwidth,
            axis lines=middle,
            xlabel=$s$, xlabel style={anchor=west},
            ylabel style={anchor=south},
            xmin=-4,    xmax=4,
            ymin=-2,    ymax=2,
            xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty  % <---
            ]
            \addplot [
            domain=-3.8:3.8,
            samples=100,
            thick, smooth,
            ] {sin(deg(3*x))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `ticks=none` to your code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\usepackage[margin = 0.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            height=5.5cm, width=0.8*\textwidth,
            axis lines=middle,
            %grid, grid style = {dashed},
            xlabel=$s$, xlabel style={anchor=west},
            ylabel style={anchor=south},
            xmin=-4, xmax=4,
            ymin=-3,  ymax=3,
            xticklabels=none, yticklabels=none,
            ticks=none
            ]
            \addplot [
            domain=-3.8:3.8, 
            samples=100, 
            thick, smooth,
            ] {sin(deg(3*x))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]